Check if an UUID exists in Table A or Table B using Validation Rules (Laravel Validation)?
In my Laravel application, I would like to check wether the value of the field uuid is present in table courses or in table contingents using validation rules. The UUID must be present in one of the two tables to proceed. Laravel requires the UUID to be present in both tables, when I'm applying the following ruleset:
$request->validate([
   'uuid' => 'exists:courses,course_id',
   'uuid' => 'exists:contingents,contingent_id
]);

Some kind of “differentiation logic” is required. It would be possible to achieve it with some if statements, but that wouldn't be a very clean way to solve the problem, I guess.
How can I tell Laravel that the UUID only needs to exist in ONE table for validation to be ok?
Thanks in advance.

I think you can achieve this by creating a custom validation rule in Laravel and then use in your request.

Yeah, this will need to be a custom rule. As written, ['uuid' => '...', 'uuid' => '...'], the 2nd exists logic will be the only one checked, since Array keys need to be unique, and if they're not, the "last" one takes precedence. The documentation is pretty good for Custom Rules though: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

you can create custom validation rule using php artisan make:rule ticketNumberIsNotUsed
class TicketNumberIsNotUsed implements Rule
{
  public function __construct(protected array $tables = [])
  {}

  public function passes($attribute, $value)
  {
    // Check if the UUID exists in either of the tables
    foreach ($this->tables as $table => $field) {
      if (DB::table($table)->where($field, $value)->exists()) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
...

use App\Rules\TicketNumberIsNotUsed;

$request->validate([
   'uuid' => ['required', new TicketNumberIsNotUsed([
     // list of table => field to search in order
     'courses' => 'course_id',
     'contingents' => 'contingent_id',
    ])],
]);


I like the abstraction, and yours is the only answer that short-circuits if record is found in the first table (i.e. best performance). Good stuff

Great solution, thank you very much!

you can use custom validation rule
first of all make new rule using php artisan make:rule ruleName.
now write this function in the rule class
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    // Check if the UUID exists in either courses or contingents table
    $existsInCourses = DB::table('courses')->where('course_id', $value)->exists();
    $existsInContingents = DB::table('contingents')->where('contingent_id', $value)->exists();

    return $existsInCourses || $existsInContingents;
}

after that use it in your controller like that
use App\Rules\RuleName;

// Inside your controller method
$request->validate([
   'uuid' => ['required', new RuleName],
]);


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;    

$request->validate([
    'uuid' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $courseExists = DB::table('courses')->where('course_id', $value)->exists();
            $contingentExists = DB::table('contingents')->where('contingent_id', $value)->exists();

            if (!$courseExists && !$contingentExists) {
                $fail('The :attribute must exist in either the courses or contingents table.');
            }
        },
    ],
]);

